# display all nodes except one type of node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphdb

I have a project that I work on, that looking to display relations between symptoms and treatments.
I want to add the option to add a TAG to every node (symptom or treatments) for classification,
But the issue is when I'm looking for a path or to display all nodes I don't want the TAG relation to be used.

is there a way to ask a cypher to display all nodes except one type (the TAG node and the tag relation)?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
MATCH (n) 
// excluding the :TAG nodes
WHERE NOT n:TAG 
//or nodes that have a :TAG relationship
OR EXISTS (n)-[:TAG]->()

RETURN n
```